# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this problem with VueJS Laravel

This is my Home.vue

```
<template>
    <table>
        <tr v-for="models in model.data">
            {{models.nom}}
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default{
    data() {
        return {
            model: {}
        }
    },
    created:function(){
        this.fetchDataResto()
    },
    methods: {
        fetchDataResto(){
            var vm = this
            axios.get('/test')
                .then(function response(){
                    Vue.set(vm.$data, 'model', response.model.data)
                })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is my app.js

```
require("./bootstrap");
window.Vue = require("vue");
Vue.component('home', require('./components/Home.vue'));

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

I have this message error after execute `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at response (app.js:47293)`

I don't know why data is undefined

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solve with this

```
fetchDataResto(){
                var vm = this
                axios.get('/test')
                    .then(function (response){
                        Vue.set(vm.model, 'model', response.data)
                    })
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetchDataResto(){
            var vm = this
            axios.get('/test')
                .then(function (response){
                    Vue.set(vm.$data, 'model', response.model.data)
                })
        }
```

You forgot to set the `response` variable. ;)